# Paperjs SVG import: How to access group id's

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

In paperjs I'm importing an SVG file that has elements like this:

```
<g id="Layer_4">
    <circle fill="#F42700" cx="114.5" cy="249.5" r="50"/>
    <circle fill="#F42700" cx="385.5" cy="249.5" r="50"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_3">
    <path fill="#8A0055" d="M408,263l-36-0.3V38c0-0.3-..."/>
</g>
```

Those top level groups are accessible in the parsed SVG as direct children of the created SVG object. But aside from their order, is there any way I can retrieve the original `id` parameter?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("g")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top level group `ids` turn into `item.name` parameters, like:

```
paper.project.import("path/to/svg.svg", function (item) {
    console.log(item.firstChild.name)
}
```

As per [this comment](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1348).